# How to draw the center of mass of a scatter plot in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, statistics

I have created a scatter plot in Excel, and I'd like to be able to draw its center of mass (i.e. the point whose coordinates is the average of each series).

I am currently doing it using this trick:

1. I add the center of mass as an additional point to my series, using `average` function to compute its x- and y-coordinates.
2. I generate my scatter plot using the button "Insert > Scatter plot"
3. I identify and color that point in a different color.

This works fine, and is easy to do when I have a small number of points. But it is much more tedious when I have to deal with a large number of points (e.g. 5000 points).

Therefore, is there any more efficient way to do this? I searched a lot for this, but I was not able to find anything.... :(

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the *center mass* point as a second series (just one point) with its own formatting and labeling.

In fact, you could just use named ranges for the *center mass* point, and plot the ranges. There's no need for it to be actually calculated in a spreadsheet cell.

**UPDATE**
To use the name range:

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table (not absolutely necessary, but simplifies updates and formulas, and generally a good practice).
2. Add a named range for your average X and Y values.  Assuming your table is named `Table1` (the default) and your *X column* is named `x` and your *Y column* is named `y`, you'd have two named ranges:
   `avg_x =AVERAGE(Table1[x])`
   `avg_y =AVERAGE(Table1[y])`
3. Add a series to your chart with the
   `X series =sheet1!avg_x`
   `Y series =sheet1!avg_y`

Then, whenever your table is updated, your *center mass* point will automatically update.

Comment: Adding the center mass point as a second series is much more elegant!

Comment: However, I don't understand how to do it without calculating the center mass point coordinates in a spreadsheet cell... I don't see how using named ranges for the center mass point can help here. Can you please elaborate?